# React diplay objects that have lists within them

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the below prop being passed in my  component, which should then display it.

```
const userData = {'name':'Tom','hobbies':['Basketball','Judo']}
const userDataDisplay = props => {
return (
<>
   <h2>{props.name}</h2>
   <p>{props.hobbies.map(hobby=><li>{hobby}</li>)}</p>
</>
)
}
```

But When I add another user, both the usernames come first and then the hobbies, when what I need is the hobbies for each user to come after the name.

```
 Tom
 Sam

Basketball
Judo
Carrom
```

appears instead of

```
 Tom
Basketball
Judo

 Sam
Carrom
```

What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: can you show me what is your userData after adding a new user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to have multiple users you will need an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), you only have one user object. If you have an array you can loop over all the users using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the same way you already loop over your hobbies.

Second, list items `<li>` only really make sense within a list `<ul>` or `<ol>`. And in fact what you want is a [nested list](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_nested) so you should use nested lists.

Here a working solution which reflects the abovementioned changes.

```js
const userData = [
  { name: "Tom", hobbies: ["Basketball", "Judo"] },
  { name: "Sam", hobbies: ["Carrom", "Football"] },
];

const UserDataDisplay = ({ userData }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {userData.map((user) => (
        <li>
          <ul>
            <h2>{user.name}</h2>
            {user.hobbies.map((hobby) => (
                <li>{hobby}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserDataDisplay userData={userData} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had one more question... Why are you passing userData as an object here? --> 
 const UserDataDisplay = ({ userData }) => ---- Shouldn't just (userData) work? It's not and your answer is what works, but it's got me confused.

Comment: React passes the props as an object with whatever you pass as properties of that object. Therefore if you have it like this `(userData)` you would need to access the actual `userData` using `userData.userData` which is an unnecessary inconvenience therefore I (and pretty much all React developers) use [object destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring). You can try to use `(userData)` and log it within your component to see that is is an object like this `{ userData: <actual user data> }`.

Comment: Again, thanks @Mushroomator for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

that's because you need to first loop thorough your array and then base on each hobby display both h2 tag and p tag